# How to submit map_blocks operation to a Client

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to chunk-wise evaluate a funtion on a dask array. I can successfully do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
arr = np.random.randint(0, 9, (4, 4))
darr = da.from_array(arr, chunks=(2, 2))

def block_mean(block):
    return np.array([[block.mean()]])
r = darr.map_blocks(block_mean)
out_arr = r.compute()
```

How can I replicate this in a `Client`? I tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
arr = np.random.randint(0, 9, (4, 4))
darr = da.from_array(arr, chunks=(2, 2))

def block_mean(block):
    return np.array([[block.mean()]])
r = darr.map_blocks(block_mean)
c = Client()

# The following does not work
out = c.submit(r)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep this very short: you need not do anything at all; if you define a `Client`, it will become the default scheduler, and `.compute()` uses the default scheduler (unless specified).

```
r = darr.map_blocks(block_mean)
c = Client()
out_arr = r.compute()
```

If you read the docs for [`submit`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.submit), it expects a function - there are plenty of examples of how to use it.